# Error with copy constructor

Tags: c++, memory-management, copy-constructor

My program keeps dyeing when trying to allocate new memory for my array. By calling the add word function. Any help would be great!

Full code download @ http://www.johnsoncomputertechnologies.org/pgm2demo.zip

```
#include <iomanip>    //Standard IO Manipulators Library
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>   //Standard input/output library
#include <string>     //Standard string Library
#include <cassert>    //Error handeling Library
#include "pgm2.h"
using namespace std;
    dictionary::dictionary()
    {
        wordptr = new value_type[DICTONARY_CAPACITY];
        deffptr = new value_type[DICTONARY_CAPACITY];
        used = 0;
    }

    dictionary::dictionary(const dictionary& other)
    {
        value_type *wordptr;
        value_type *deffptr;
        wordptr = new value_type[other.capacity];
        deffptr = new value_type[other.capacity];
        used = other.used;
        capacity = other.capacity + 1;
        copy(wordptr, other.wordptr + used, other.wordptr);
        copy(deffptr, other.deffptr + used, other.deffptr);

    }

    dictionary::~dictionary()
    {
        delete [] wordptr;
        delete [] deffptr;
    }

    //Functions
    void dictionary::reserve(size_type new_capacity)
    {
        value_type *larger_word;
        value_type *larger_deff;
        if(new_capacity == capacity)
            return; //There allocated memory is already the correct size
        if(new_capacity < used)
            new_capacity = used;

        larger_word = new value_type[new_capacity];
        larger_deff = new value_type[new_capacity];
        copy(wordptr, wordptr + used, larger_word);
        copy(deffptr, deffptr + used, larger_deff);
        delete [] wordptr;
        delete [] deffptr;
        wordptr = larger_word;
        deffptr = larger_deff;
        capacity = new_capacity;
    }
    void dictionary::addword(const value_type& word, const value_type& deff)
    {
        if(used == capacity)
            reserve(used+1);
        wordptr[used] = word;
        deffptr[used] = deff;
        ++used;
    }

    void dictionary::containsPat (value_type patt)
    {
        size_type i;
        size_type finds;
        int found = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < used; i++)
        {
            finds = wordptr[i].find(patt);

            if (finds != std::string::npos)
            {
                cout << wordptr[i] << "  -  " << deffptr[i] << endl;
                found = 1;
            }
        }
        if (found == 0)
            cout << "*** No words contain the pattern '" << patt << "'" << endl;
    }
    void dictionary::endPat(value_type patt)
    {
        size_type i;
        size_type finds;
        int found = 0;
        size_type pos;

        for(i = 0; i < used; i++)
        {
            finds = wordptr[i].find(patt);

            pos = wordptr[i].length() - patt.length();

            if (finds == pos)
            {
                cout << wordptr[i] << "  -  " << deffptr[i] << endl;
                found = 1;
            }
        }
        if (found == 0)
            cout << "*** No words end with pattern '" << patt << "'" << endl;
    }
    void dictionary::startPat(value_type patt)
    {
        size_type i;
        size_type finds;
        int found = 0;
        for(i = 0; i < used; i++)
        {
            finds = wordptr[i].find(patt);

            if (finds == 0)
            {
                cout << wordptr[i] << "  -  " << deffptr[i] << endl;
                found = 1;
            }
        }
        if (found == 0)
            cout << "*** No words begin with pattern '" << patt << "'" << endl;
    }

    void dictionary::print()
    {
        size_type i;
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        cout << "---                             Dictionary Words and Meanings                                          ---" << endl;
        cout << "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------" << endl;
        for(i = 0; i < used; i++)
        {
            cout << wordptr[i] << "   -   " << deffptr[i] << endl;
        }
        cout << "There are " << used << " words in the dictionary!" <<     endl;

    }
```

### pgm2.h

```
#include <iomanip>    //Standard IO Manipulators Library
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>   //Standard input/output library
#include <string>     //Standard string Library
#include <cassert>    //Error handeling Library
using namespace std;

class dictionary
{
public:
    typedef string value_type;
    typedef std::size_t size_type;
    static const size_type DICTONARY_CAPACITY = 25;

    //Default Constructor
    dictionary();
    dictionary(dictionary& other);
    //Destructor
    ~dictionary();

    //Functions
    void reserve(size_type new_capacity);
    void addword(const value_type& word, const value_type& deff);
    void startPat (value_type patt);
    void endPat(value_type patt);
    void containsPat(value_type patt);

    void print();

private:
    value_type *wordptr;
    value_type *deffptr;
    size_type used;
    size_type capacity;
};
```

Comment: Please add the dictionary class declaration

Comment: It is included in the download link, but give me a min and i will past it as well

Comment: You need an operator=.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain is right, see the [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)).

Comment: Your code is also full of the possibility of memory leaks.

Comment: The Rule of Three is one solution, although you'll have a hard time ensuring exception safety while managing two dynamic resources. Better would be the Rule of Zero: use `std::vector` or similar to manage the dynamic arrays, rather than juggling the pointers yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see you reset `capacity` anywhere in the code... Might cause your reserve() call not to be called.

Answer (score 5):

Your copy constructor is setting local variables rather than the members, so the member pointers remain uninitialized.

P.S. The declaration should use `const dictionary&` since you shouldn't modify the dictionary you're copying.